# Which version of Oracle Client should I install?

Tags: python, oracle

I need to run some SQL queries using Python in Oracle 9i database, Which version of Oracle I should install for this purpose. I am using cx_Oracle and Python 3.7 on Windows 10 machine.

I get this error message: "cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: DPI-1047: 64-bit Oracle Client library cannot be loaded:"

Answer (score 2):

You need oracle client 11 or 10. Oracle client 12 can not connect to oracle 9i. The oracle client libraries must be either 32-bit or 64-bit, matching your Python architecture.

```
    C:\oracle\instantclient_12_2>.\sqlplus.exe scott/tiger@test

    SQL*Plus: Release 12.2.0.1.0 Production on Thu Feb 7 14:39:09 2019

    Copyright (c) 1982, 2017, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

    ERROR:
    ORA-03134: Connections to this server version are no longer supported.


    Enter user-name:

C:\oracle\instantclient_11_2>.\sqlplus.exe scott/tiger@test

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.4.0 Production on Thu Feb 7 14:39:58 2019

Copyright (c) 1982, 2013, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle9i Enterprise Edition Release 9.2.0.8.0 - Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP and Oracle Data Mining options
JServer Release 9.2.0.8.0 - Production

SQL>
```

Comment: Ok I understood, but I need to run Python program in order to connect. Here you have simply used sqlPlus.exe to connect....how can I invoke sql PLus from my python code ???   thanks a ton for your help

Comment: @kushagraparashar That is an entirely different question that is outside the scope of the one you asked. If this answer has answered what your question actually asked then mark it as the accepted answer. If the question did not get the answer you wanted because you didn't ask the correct thing then ask a new question; don't ask unrelated follow up question in comments.

Answer (score 0):

Recent versions of cx_Oracle require 11.2 or later Oracle client libraries. Luckily Oracle client 11.2 will connect to Oracle DB 9.2 and later DBs. From the error message you need a 64-bit version, which you can get using the free [Oracle Instant Client](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winx64soft-089540.html).

Review the cx_Oracle installation manual section [Oracle Client and Oracle Database Interoperability](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#oracle-client-and-oracle-database-interoperability).

If you are new to cx_Oracle, look at the [tutorial](https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/tree/master/samples/tutorial) and [samples](https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/tree/master/samples).  cx_Oracle runs individual SQL statements; it does not run SQL*Plus scripts (with multiple statements)